# Firebase allow android apps to connect to your database

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

How do you get other users and clients to connect your database instance?

I know you connect to it this way:

`FirebaseDatabase database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();`

But how do you specify which database you want to connect to? There is no IP address or host name.

What is `getInstance()` referring to?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Typically you download/include `google-services.json` file for your app from Firebase Console.  More details in following

https://firebase.google.com/docs/android/setup

and it's that info that's used then to initialize Firebase database instance (and potentially other Firebase services)

Answer (score 0):

copy "google-services.json" in your folder Application/app

FirebaseDatabase database = FirebaseStorage.getInstance().getReference();